# SSRS ReportViewer Datepicker in Chrome

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Having trouble getting the jQuery DatePicker to appear in non-IE browsers.

Comment: See the browser console to find errors; click F12 key and look for console. change `if (span)` to `if (span.length)`, your html should be well-formed

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should correct the HTML:

```
<div>
    <form>
        <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer" Style="display: table !important; margin: 0px; overflow: auto !important;" runat="server"></rsweb:ReportViewer>
    </form>
</div>
```

And there is no need to call document.ready 2 times - both youve used do the same

```
$(function () {
    showDatePicker();
});
```

"If span" wont work - you need to use if(span.length):

```
function showDatePicker() {
    var parameterRow = $("#ParametersRowReportViewer");
    var innerTable = $(parameterRow).find("table").find("table");
    var span = innerTable.find("span:contains('From Date:')");
    if(span.length) {
        ....
    }
}
```

Maybe these changes will solve your problem.

---

**EDIT**

You need to change the script to:

```
var innerRow = $(span).parents('tr').eq(0); // changed
var innerCell = innerRow.find('td').eq(1);
var textFrom = innerCell.find('input[type="text"]'); // changed
innerCell = innerRow.find('td').eq(4);
var textTo = innerCell.find('input[type="text"]'); // changed
```

Because of the ASP-Script-Stuff i had to add this too (to disable it for fiddle):

```
// Remove ASP-Scripts onClick-stuff
$('div').add('td').attr('onclick', '');

// Remove input disabled="disabled"
$('input').removeAttr('disabled');
```

See [this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8wcenq6f/7/).

I hope this helps.

Comment: What messages do you get from the debug console? (F12) Could you create a Fiddle?

Comment: You could press F12 and post the generated HTML from there to a fiddle.

Comment: Maybe one of the ASP-scripts causing this? It works for you in the fiddle i posted above? There could be something like onchange->this attr=disabled. You could remove that inside the "datepicker->onClose()"

Comment: Seems you havn't included the jQueryUI-CSS properly:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

Comment: where is this file located ? im trying to fix the datepicker in chrome thanks